# How do I lock my mouse within the Remote Desktop window with a dual monitor setup?

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop, windows-server-2003, multiple-monitors

I have a dual monitor setup, 24" widescreen primary and 19" 4:3 secondary, turned vertically, on the right side.

My workstation is Windows XP, and I am using Remote Desktop to get onto a Windows Server 2003 virtual machine.  The Remote Desktop session is in full screen and on my primary monitor.

Is there any way to lock my mouse within that Remote Desktop window so that moving my mouse cursor to the right doesn't make it leave the Remote Desktop environment and into my workstation environment?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any settings within RDP that would prevent what you would describe.
One possible solution (short of programming) would be run the 2nd monitor on another machine.  Then you could connect the two machines via a KVM (real or software) which would require a manual switch to 'jump' to the 19" monitor from the 24".